# Itemscontrol with ending control

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I'm having a `ItemsControl` with custom controls wrapped inside. What I want to achieve is to always have a `TextBox` control along with my custom controls always at the end of `WrapPanel`.

Here is a slight preview:

[image]

Having `ItemsControl` allows us to have controls of the same type. When `TextBox`is added after `ItemsControl`, it will unfortunately appear on the new line. Therefore I'm forced to somehow append `TextBox` along with my custom controls in `ItemsControl`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">   
    <!--  Make items wrap  -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!--  Custom control  -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <local:CustomControl />

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>

<!-- This should be inside items control -->
<TextBox />
```

I did some research and it turns out that I can use `DataTemplateSelector` class and `ItemTemplateSelector` which will allow me to choose template for different items.

This is an option of course, however it will require me to insert TextBox into my `MyItems` (which is ObservableCollection btw.) and I'm not sure if this is the way to go since I will have to locate TextBox and move it at the end of my `ObservableCollection`, each time a new item is added...

So the question is: what is the proper way to solve this? Looking for experienced developers opinion on this.

Comment: Yeah its a very specific problem and there is no "proper" way just the way you are happy with. id lean towards `DataTemplateSelector` and putting all the controls in your collection, and if you want to add, just insert at the end of the list. You could probably do this otherways though, it just seems logical to me

Comment: @TheGeneral Is `ObservableCollection` desired to contain multiple entity types? I don't think this is possible. Turns out I'd need to add `CustomControlViewModel` entity and `CustomControlTextBoxViewModel`... so perhaps there is another collection type holder for this?

Comment: Yeah sorry i miss interpreted your design a little, maybe an interface, however rethinking this im not sure if its going to help you.

Comment: @TheGeneral Yeah, cannot find a good and clean solution for this. One way to go I can think of is to create a boolean property inside `CustomControlViewModel` and if it's true, then in my `DataTemplateSelector` I could go for `TextBox` template instead of `CustomControl` template but man, that would be so badly designed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the `ItemsSource` to a [CompositeCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-a-compositecollection):

```
<ItemsControl ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding MyItems}" />
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" />
            <!-- This should be inside items control: -->
            <TextBox />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    <!--  Make items wrap  -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <!--  Custom control  -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CustomControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Great solution :-) Gonna give it a try!